# Vaadin 23 select DatePicker content at onfocus in dialog

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23, vaadin-date-picker

**DatePicker behavior in view**: In a Vaadin 23 application there is a view with two DatePickers and a button:

[image: Vaadin view with 2 DatePicker and button]

When a user steps between the fields with TAB, then the `DatePicker` marks the whole content as selected (which is fine and the intended behavior):

[image: TAB selects the whole content of DatePicker]

**DatePicker behavior in Dialog is different**: When I put two `DatePicker` instances into a `Dialog` then the TAB behavior is different: it does not mark the whole content, but sets the focus after the content:

[image: Vaadin dialog with 2 DatePicker]

**Code**:

```
@Route("sandbox")
public class SandboxView extends VerticalLayout {

public SandboxView() {
    this.add(createDatePicker(), createDatePicker());
    this.add(new Button("Open dialog", event -> {
        openDialog();
    }));
}

private void openDialog() {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(createDatePicker(), createDatePicker());
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(layout);
    dialog.open();
}

private DatePicker createDatePicker() {
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    datePicker.setAutoOpen(false);
    return datePicker;
}
}
```

**Intended behavior**: I'd like the `DatePicker` to show the same behavior in a `Dialog` as it is in a view.

**Question**: How can I do this?

**What I tried**: When a focus listener calls `select()` at the INPUT child node in JavaScript (see code below), the whole content is marked/selected (which is as intended). But this also marks/selects the whole content when the user clicks with the mouse into the field (which is not intended).

```
field.getElement().addEventListener("focus", new DomEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(DomEvent event) {
        event.getSource().executeJs("for (var i=0;i<$0.childNodes.length;i++){if($0.childNodes[i].nodeName=='INPUT'){$0.childNodes[i].select();}}");
    }
});
```

**Update for TextField**: When using `TextField`s instead of `DatePicker`s, it's the same behavior: in a view a TAB marks/selects the whole content. In a `Dialog` a TAB sets the focus before the content, but does not mark/select it:

[image: Vaadin Dialog with two TextField s]

Comment: I assume the focus gets lost when opening the dialog. Have you tried to call focus() on the datapicker?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: when I call `firstComponent.getElement().executeJs("$0.focus();for (var i=0;i<$0.childNodes.length;i++){if($0.childNodes[i].nodeName=='INPUT'){$0.childNodes[i].select();}}");` after `dialog.open();`, then the first component/inputfield is focused after opening the dialog. That works fine. And when pressing the TAB key, the second component/inputfield is focused (OK). But the content is not selected. This is another behavior as it is when the component/inputfield is outside of a dialog.

Comment: That's an interesting behavior indeed. I would suggest you open a bug report https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/

Comment: Bug report is created here: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is fixed in Vaadin 23.1.6.